# SVG files are nested with a large number of<use>tags, resulting in rendering errors

Tags: java, svg

I have an SVG file with a lot of  nesting inside it. So although the file size is small, a lot of memory is used when rendering. Want to know how to use Java to distinguish this type of SVG file from other types of SVG files.

```
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="a" d="M0,0"/>
<g id="b"><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><use xlink:href="#a"/></g>
<g id="c"><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"/></g>
<g id="d"><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/><use xlink:href="#c"/></g>
<g id="e"><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/><use xlink:href="#d"/></g>
<g id="f"><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/><use xlink:href="#e"/></g>
<g id="g"><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/><use xlink:href="#f"/></g>
<g id="h"><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/><use xlink:href="#g"/></g>
<g id="i"><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/><use xlink:href="#h"/></g>
<g id="j"><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/><use xlink:href="#i"/></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If this question is related to the programming language Java then add the Java tag to your question.

Comment: This is indeed an exploit AKA "Billion laughs attack". You might translate the JS concept described here [How to identify if SVG is consuming all browser's memory and snaps the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75066403/how-to-identify-if-svg-is-consuming-all-browsers-memory-and-snaps-the-window/75091943#75091943) to java